# Using StringCollectionEditor with thread safe List

Tags: c#, list, collections, properties, thread-safety

I'm trying to expose my List class member via a Windows Forms Property Grid using System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor.  My question is regarding thread-safety

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]

public List<string> EventLogSources {
        get {
            lock (lockObj) {
                return eventLogSources;
            }
        }  
}
```

Obviously this isn't thread safe since multiple threads could get the reference and update it.  So what is the best way to use StringCollectionEditor (or something similar) and be thread safe?

Comment: Basically, another way of looking at it is that I need to provide the real eventLogSources List to the StringCollectionEditor (a copy won't do because then it won't be editable).  But at the same time I need to keep others client code from editing it.

Comment: What makes this easier is the fact that only the user will be expected to update the strings in the list, and all other threads will read the data.  THEREFORE, if behind the scenes the StringCollectionEditor doesn't modify the contents of the array, but instead simply assigns a new array (with the new/modified contents) to the EventLogSources property, then I believe I should be ok.  I'm tempted to close the question, but what I don't understand is why StringCollectionEditor doesn't therefore require a setter on the EventLogSources property

Answer (score 0):

The code from http://mastersact.blogspot.com/2007/06/string-collection-editor-for-property.html looks like it will do the trick:

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
IServiceProvider serviceprovider, object value)
{
if (serviceprovider != null)
{
mapiEditorService = serviceprovider
.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as
IWindowsFormsEditorService;
}

if (mapiEditorService != null)
{
StringCollectionForm form = new StringCollectionForm();

// Retrieve previous values entered in list.
if (value != null)
{
List stringList = (List)value;
form.txtListValues.Text = String.Empty;
foreach (string stringValue in stringList)
{
form.txtListValues.Text += stringValue + "\r\n";
}
}

// Show Dialog.
form.ShowDialog();

if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
List stringList = new List();

string[] listSeparator = new string[1];
listSeparator[0] = "\r\n";

string[] listValues = form.txtListValues.Text
.Split(listSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Add list values in list.
foreach (string stringValue in listValues)
{
stringList.Add(stringValue);
}

value = stringList;
}

return value;
}

return null;
}
```